# What am I missing from running background tasks in-process? [Python, Gevent, Flask]

Tags: python, flask, task, gevent

I am writing a Gevent/Flask server in Python. Some of the requests my Flask app takes need to run in the background; there is an endpoint for the client to poll the server for the task's result.

If you search the wisdom of the Internet for the best way to do this, everybody seems to be in favor of setting up one or several worker processes such as Celery or RQ, with a message queue or store such as RabbitMQ or Redis.

My app is small and my deployment is modest. This seems like too much of a hassle for me. I already have cooperative multitasking with Gevent, so I thought I'd just create a greenlet to do the background work in-process, that is, within the Flask app process itself.

This is not the mainstream solution, so my question is: Am I missing something? What am I missing? Is there something in this solution that makes it particularly bad?

Comment: Well, setting up Celery/RabbitMQ for a smallish app may indeed be an overkill, but RQ is perfect for lightweight queues and takes no time to set up.

Comment: No time? You need to set up a Redis backend and it has its own workers... For a modest app, I just don't see the benefit.

Comment: I'm mostly using Heroku  so there's no administering overhead and it literally takes one click to setup. On a local box you just have to run redis daemon, no special setup needed.

Comment: 1 click and $15/month... and there's no Redis for Windows.

Comment: Flask apps were meant to run in a single thread. If your greenlets make use of the framework's methods, that would be considered unsafe. That being said, I have taken your approach (carefully) more than once and it worked just fine (just had to let uWSGI know I'm using threads now). God speed